# Passing wordpress template_directory_uri() to acf-maps.js

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps-api-3, advanced-custom-fields

I can't seem to figure this out.

I'm using Wordpress with advanced custom fields and custom post types in order to display a map with the location associated with those custom post types.

I'm using MarkerClusterer and wanted to customize the icons for it, and don't want to hardcode the path to the image.

I understand I should use wp_localize but don't know how to do it.

I have a functions.php file in my theme folder where I think I must pass template_directory_uri() as a variable.

I have a /js/acf_maps.js in my theme folder that needs to read that variable, i.e., instead of hardcoding this in the js file:

```
url: 'http://mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/clustercustomicon.png'
```

I wanted to have

```
http://mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/
```

passed as variable and only add the relative path to the customized icon.

Hope this makes sense.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer passing variables with `wp_localize_script`.

```
$array['theme_url'] = template_directory_uri();
wp_localize_script( 'enqueue_handle', 'variable', $array);
```

Then access the variable with variable.theme_url in the javascript.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: Yes, from what I read it's the way to go, but can you please elaborate? If I place the code you provided in functions.php I get Call to undefined function template_directory_uri()

Comment: Call it while you enqueue acf-map.js. Replace the "enqueue_handle" with the same handle as acf-map.js, but make sure to call it after you register the acf-map.js.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. Just had to replace template_directory_uri() with get_template_directory_uri() !

Answer (score 1):

If you create a global javascript variable, you will be able to access it in other js files

```
var theme_url = '<?php echo template_directory_uri(); ?>';
```

and in js file,

```
var icon = window.theme_url+'/img/clustercustomicon.png';
```

Comment: right now it helped pointing me into a working way to do this! Thanks: I have placed this code in functions.php: `// defining global JS variables
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'js_vars' );
function js_vars(){ ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 var wp_template_dir = <?php echo json_encode (get_template_directory_uri()); ?>;  
  </script>
  <?php
}` and this one in the js: `url: wp_template_dir + '/img/cluster.png'` . I think using wp localize is better options but at least this one works well!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Managed to do with with wp_localize but your method is also useful and maybe handy sometimes, thanks